Works on Aristotle deductive system
This year, I have to write a term paper. I want to focus on Aristotle's logic, and more specifically, his deductive system. Could you advise me on:

The most valuable or fundamental articles on this topic from the last 5 to 15 years?

The most valuable or fundamental articles of all time?



John Corcoran's studies as well as Stephen Read.

Also relevant books by Jan Lukasiewicz and G.Patzig.

A classic text is Kneale and Kneale, The Development of Logic, chapter 2, Arisotle's Organon. Another comprehensive source is the Handbook of the History of Logic, eds Gabbay and Woods, Volume 1, chapters 2 through 4. The SEP article on Aristotle's Logic is a good introduction and has several references for further reading.

Perhaps of interest in terms of formalizing syllogistic logic is the work of Larry Moss on natural logic. A paper that comes to mind is “completeness theorems for syllogistic fragments”. While this work is a modern take on syllogistic logic, it’s not really doing any historical work. So if that’s what you are after, then perhaps this will not be what you are looking for.
